# How to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 8.1 on Lenovo IdeaPad?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I’m not understanding the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 as dual boot. I know how to run the Ubuntu LiveDVD without installing. Can anyone guide me on how to install Ubuntu along with Windows 8.1 on Lenovo IdeaPad?

Answer (score 0):

As the installer says, the option "Install alongside W8.1" installs Ubuntu 14.04 with dual boot in parallel with W8.1. Basically it does:

- Shrink the size of your partitions to allocate some space for Ubuntu
- Create a new partition for holding the Ubuntu SO.
- Install all SO contents to that new partition
- Install the GRUB2 bootloader in the MBR and configure for dual boot

When installation is complete, it is recommended to boot W8.1 at least once for forcing the `chkdsk` utility to execute to make sure that no data loss occured.

---

In my experience, I prefer to modify the partitions manually, to make sure everything fits properly onto disk ("Modify partitions manually"). Ubuntu requires about 10GiB, but if you like to install too many apps (such as compilers or heavy games) I recommend having more than 32GiB. And also you have to make another partition for holding the swap partition, which the suggested size should be equal to the amount of RAM installed (if done so, hibernation will be allowed). So this is basically what I do (consid:

- Shrink the Windows partition about 40GiB.
- Create a **EXTENDED** partition, it'll allow me to use more partitions than the 4 physical partitions available.
- Create a ext4 partition with size 40GiB - *r*, where *r* is the size of your RAM **inside the extended**.
- Create a swap partition with size *r* **inside the extended**.
- Tell the installer to install Ubuntu in the ext4 partition.
- Format both partitions (the ext4 & swap) prior to install (mandatory!)
- Install GRUB2 in the disk and outside any partiton (eg. if Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda5, install it in /dev/sda)

Let me know if you had any problems! Glad to help!